# how to convert ihttpactionresult return to string

Tags: c#, webapi

I am new to C# and am trying to get a value from the return of ihttpactionresult to a variable.

However I am having difficulty in this . This is my method:

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("GetUserRole")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetUserRole()
        {
            ManageUserData ObjManageUserData = new ManageUserData();
            string UserRole = string.Empty;
            var dt = ObjManageUserData.GetUserRole(UserPersonalNumber);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                UserRole = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
            else
                UserRole = "User";
            return Ok(UserRole);
        }
```

In UserRole I am getting value from a table which is equal to SMPAG. I am trying to get this value to a variable in another string however I am having difficulties.

The other method is :

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("GetTableValue")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetTableValue()
        {
            try
            {
                List<UserModel> userModels = new List<UserModel>();

                var UserID = UserAdId;

                var UserRole = GetUserRole().ToString();

                return Ok(UserRole );
                }
```

I am trying to get the value SMPAG from GetUserRole() function into userRole and do some manipulation however I am getting some other value other than the string passed how do I get the string value of SMPAG in this variable. Could you please help?

Comment: Try to cast the return value of the GetUserRole() method call to [OkObjectResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.okobjectresult?view=aspnetcore-2.2). Then you can access the passed string via its Value property.

Comment: could you give a code example

Comment: var UserRole = GetUserRole() as OkObjectResult; return Ok(UserRole.Value);

Comment: Is your issue still outstanding?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going about this in the wrong way. You have a common need for the user's role as a `string` value, right? But the `GetUserRole` web method returns an `IHttpActionResult`. So you're effectively generating a string value, wrapping it up, and then you want to unwrap it again to use it.

The introduction of a third method, `GetUserRoleImplementation` (or what ever name makes sense to you), will help with this:

```cs
private string GetUserRoleImplementation()
{
    ManageUserData ObjManageUserData = new ManageUserData();
    string UserRole = string.Empty;
    var dt = ObjManageUserData.GetUserRole(UserPersonalNumber);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        UserRole = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
    else
        UserRole = "User";
}
```

You can see that we've moved the bulk of the functionality of the existing `GetUserRole` method here. That means that `GetUserRole` now simply looks like this:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("GetUserRole")]
public IHttpActionResult GetUserRole()
{
    string userRole = GetUserRoleImplementation();
    return Ok(UserRole);
    // or just: return Ok(GetUserRoleImplementation());
}
```

And because we don't have to figure out how to extract a string value from an `IHttpActionResult` anymore, `GetTableValue` now looks like this:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("GetTableValue")]
public IHttpActionResult GetTableValue()
{
    try
    {
        List<UserModel> userModels = new List<UserModel>();

        var UserID = UserAdId;

        var UserRole = GetUserRoleImplementation();

        return Ok(UserRole );
    }
    ...
}
```